# Why don't I have any Canon printer drivers on Mac OS X 10.9 Mavericks?

Tags: macos, drivers, printer, osx-mavericks

I'm migrating from a 10.7 Mac to a new 10.9 Mac. I have a Canon Pixma iP3000 printer hooked up to an Airport Extreme, which works fine on my old machine. However, when I try to set it up on my new machine, it fails.

[image: Printers & Scanners preference pane, with "+" button pressed, menu showing "Canon iP3000"]

[image: Dialog box which says "The software for this printer is currently unavailable. Please contact the printer’s manufacturer for the latest software."]

So I try to add it manually, by choosing "Add Printer or Scanner…" It asks me to choose a driver, so I choose "Select Software…" That gives me a dialog box with a grand total of 16 drivers to choose from (12 showing, 4 more when I scroll down). None of them are Canon drivers.

[image: Printer Software dialog box, with only 16 options]

When I do the same on my old (10.7) machine, I see *hundreds* of drivers. As you can see, the first page is just the beginning of the "A"s alphabetically.

[image: Printer Software dialog box, with hundreds of options]

So: did Mountain Lion or Mavericks start shipping with almost no printer drivers? Have I done something wrong? Can I download these drivers from somewhere? Canon claims they should already be installed on my machine, and won't give me a download for them.

---

**Update:**

I tried connecting the printer directly to the Mac over USB. The dialog box only became more adamant that it didn't have a suitable driver:

[image: "Software for this printer isn't available from Apple. Contact the printer's manufacturer for the latest software."]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try the Canon CUPS driver for the IP3000 ?
It is listed on the Canon website as being for 10.6 but should work with later OSX versions too.

Comment: Perfect!  This also works for the IP5000

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with a Canon ip1700 and the following worked for me:

- Download the Combined Canon Driver from Apple (http://support.apple.com/kb/dl899 or https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1742)
- In the printer setup dialog, pick a printer with a similar number to the printer you have.

In the case of the ip1700, it isn't listed in the list of supported printers for the driver, which is why the mac doesn't auto-download it. However if you tell your mac the printer is an ip1800 then it actually works fine.

I'm guessing the same trick may also work for the ip3000.

Answer (score 0):

I tried selecting the 2700 for my 3000. I installed the drivers, tried to print and was told there was an error... BUT the Mac asked: Repair? I said yes, Mac repaired it, printer is working. Good thing, too. I still have the disc for the printer, and that *didn't* work!